# OpenCL: Invalid write of size # at global memory address 0x###

Tags: c, opencl, opencl-c

Post-solution edit: The issue is with the code alone. There is no hardware issue here. Now to the original post:

I'm trying to get a basic OpenCL program to work.

The program simply creates a buffer, writes 42 to the buffer, reads it, and outputs.

Here's the code, written in C:

```
#define MY_PLATFORM 2 // Adjustable
#define MY_DEVICE 0 // Adjustable

#include <stdio.h>

#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 200
#include <CL/cl.h>

// Simple kernel that outputs 42.
const char *myCode = " \
    __kernel void fourtyTwo(__global int *output) { \n \
        int i = get_global_id(0); \n \
        output[i] = 42; \n \
    } \n \
\0";

int main(void) {
    cl_platform_id *myPlatforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id));
    cl_uint *myPlatformCount = (cl_uint*)malloc(sizeof(cl_uint));

    cl_device_id *myDevices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id));
    cl_uint *myDeviceCount = (cl_uint*)malloc(sizeof(cl_uint));

    int err;

    /* Reference:
        cl_int clGetPlatformIDs(
            cl_uint num_entries,       // I want just enough to reach MY_PLATFORM.
            cl_platform_id *platforms, // myPlatforms
            cl_uint *num_platforms     // myPlatformCount
        )
    */
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(MY_PLATFORM + 1, myPlatforms, myPlatformCount);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not query platforms.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_int clGetDeviceIDs(
            cl_platform_id num_entries, // I want the MY_PLATFORM'th entry of myPlatforms.
            cl_device_type device_type, // Any device will do.
            cl_uint num_entries,        // I want just enough to reach MY_DEVICE.
            cl_device_id *devices,      // myDevices
            cl_uint *num_devices        // myDeviceCount
        )
    */
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(myPlatforms[MY_PLATFORM], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, MY_DEVICE + 1, myDevices, myDeviceCount);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not query devices.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_context clCreateContext(
            cl_context_properties *properties, // The default properties should suffice.
            cl_uint num_devices,               // I want just enough to reach MY_DEVICE.
            const cl_device_id *devices,       // myDevices
            void *pfn_notify,                  // No need for this.
            void *user_data,                   // No need for this.
            cl_int *errcode_ret                // err
        )
    */
    cl_context myContext = clCreateContext(NULL, MY_DEVICE + 1, myDevices, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not open context.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_command_queue clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(
            cl_context context,                   // myContext
            cl_device_id device,                  // I want the MY_DEVICE'th device of myDevices.
            const cl_queue_properties properties, // The default properties should suffice.
            cl_int *errcode_ret                   // err
        )
    */
    cl_command_queue myCommandQueue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(myContext, myDevices[MY_DEVICE], NULL, &err);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not open command queue.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_program clCreateProgramWithSource(
            cl_context context,    // myContext
            cl_uint count,         // There's only 1 source code.
            const char **strings,  // myCode, passed as a length-1 array.
            const size_t *lengths, // Passing NULL indicates that all the strings are null-terminated.
            cl_int *errcode_ret    // err
        )
    */
    cl_program myProgram = clCreateProgramWithSource(myContext, 1, (const char**)&myCode, NULL, &err);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not create program.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_int clBuildProgram(
            cl_program program,              // myProgram
            const cl_device_id *device_list, // myDevices
            const char *options,             // This can be NULL, right? The docs didn't specify.
            void *pfn_notify,                // No need for this.
            void *user_data                  // No need for this.
        )
    */
    err = clBuildProgram(myProgram, MY_DEVICE + 1, myDevices, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not build program.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);
        char *errLog;
        size_t errLen;
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(myProgram, myDevices[MY_DEVICE], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &errLen);
        errLog = (char*)malloc((errLen + 1) * sizeof(char));
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(myProgram, myDevices[MY_DEVICE], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, errLen, errLog, NULL);
        errLog[errLen] = 0;
        fprintf(stderr, "\nFull Build Log:\n%s\n\n", errLog);
    }

    /* Reference:
        cl_kernel clCreateKernel(
            cl_program program,      // myProgram
            const char *kernel_name, // "fourtyTwo" (See above, definition of myCode)
            cl_int *errcode_ret      // err
        )
    */
    cl_kernel myKernel = clCreateKernel(myProgram, "fourtyTwo", &err);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not create kernel.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    size_t *globalSize = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    *globalSize = 1; // There is only 1 item.
    size_t *localSize = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    *localSize = 1; // There can only be 1 out of 1 item.

    int *outputArr = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));

    /* Reference:
        cl_mem clCreateBuffer(
            cl_context context, // myContext
            cl_mem_flags flags, // I'm only writing to the output array.
            size_t size,        // Its only 1 integer.
            void *host_ptr,     // I haven't allocated this space yet.
            cl_int *errcode_ret // err
        )
    */
    cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(myContext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 1 * sizeof(int), NULL, &err);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not create buffer.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_int clSetKernelArg(
            cl_kernel kernel,     // myKernel
            cl_uint arg_index,    // Setting the 1st argument.
            size_t arg_size,      // Passing 1 cl_mem object.
            const void *arg_value // The argument shall be the output buffer for the kernel to write to.
        )
    */
    err = clSetKernelArg(myKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)outputBuffer);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not set kernel argument.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_int clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
            cl_command_queue command_queue,   // myCommandQueue
            cl_kernel kernel,                 // myKernel
            cl_uint work_dim,                 // 1 dimensional.
            const size_t *global_work_offset, // Don't offset anything.
            const size_t *global_work_size,   // globalSize
            const size_t *local_work_size,    // localSize
            cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,  // I don't have a wait list (whatever that is).
            const cl_event *event_wait_list,  // I don't have a wait list (whatever that is).
            cl_event *event                   // Don't create an event (whatever this means).
        )
    */
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(myCommandQueue, myKernel, 1, 0, globalSize, localSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not run kernel.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    /* Reference:
        cl_int clEnqueueReadBuffer(
            cl_command_queue command_queue,  // myCommandQueue
            cl_mem buffer,                   // outputBuffer
            cl_bool blocking_read,           // I'm doing everything synchronously.
            size_t offset,                   // Don't offset anything.
            size_t cb,                       // Reading in 1 integer.
            void *ptr,                       // Putting the data into outputArr.
            cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list, // I don't have a wait list (whatever that is).
            const cl_event *event_wait_list, // I don't have a wait list (whatever that is).
            cl_event *event                  // Don't create an event (whatever this means).
        )
    */
    clEnqueueReadBuffer(myCommandQueue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, 1 * sizeof(cl_int), outputArr, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if(err != 0) fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not read from buffer.\nOpenCL failed with exit code %d\n\n", err);

    // Print the result
    printf("%d\n", outputArr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

The program does not work. It leaves the buffer unchanged and throws an error through oclgrind.

Here is the output:

```
gcc main.c -o main -lOpenCL
./main

Invalid write of size 4 at global memory address 0x560d0b2cefc0
        Kernel: fourtyTwo
        Entity: Global(0,0,0) Local(0,0,0) Group(0,0,0)
          store i32 42, i32 addrspace(1)* %arrayidx, align 4, !dbg !23, !tbaa !24
        At line 3 (column 15) of input.cl:
          output[i] = 42;

0

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

In case this is a system issue, [here](https://thomaskaldahl.com/clinfo.md) is the output of `clinfo`.

I'm using an AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 4750U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 1.7000Ghz.

I'm running Arch Linux.

Does anyone have a clue as to what the issue could be? Thanks!

P.S., any criticism of my code or my question wording, whether civil or not, is welcomed by me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a buffoon. The error was on the line I went to set the kernel argument:

```
    err = clSetKernelArg(myKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)outputBuffer);
```

I typed `(void*)outputBuffer` when I should've written `(void*)&outputBuffer`. As a result of this typo, the kernel was trying to write to some arbitrary location instead of the actual position in memory of the buffer.